# GDI+ Image to HBITMAP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+

I have the following code:

```
Image *img=Image::FromFile(currentImagePath.c_str(), false);


Bitmap* pBitmap = static_cast<Bitmap*>(img/*->Clone()*/);
HBITMAP handleToSliceRet=NULL;
Status status = pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color(0,0,0), &handleToSliceRet);
```

I have initialized gdi and everything, but when I try to run this, if I uncomment the /*->Clone()*/ the debugger will say Access violation reading `0x0000` and if I leave it commented, it fails on the line `Status status = pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color(0,0,0), &handleToSliceRet);` with another access violation. I've been at this for about 6 hours now to no avail.

The current path of the image I'm trying to process is "C:\cube\cube0000.png"

Answer (score 1):

`Bitmap` derives from `Image`, not the other way around. `Image::FromFile` returns an `Image`, not a `Bitmap` - and you can't just cast it into existence.

Instead, use `Bitmap::FromFile` from the beginning to get a real `Bitmap` object.

Comment: I've tried that to no avail as well. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @kasandell Please show the code where you've "tried that". And are you checking that the image loads successfully in the first place?

Comment: '   Bitmap* bmp=Bitmap::FromFile(currentImagePath.c_str(), false);
  if(bmp->GetLastStatus()!=Gdiplus::Ok)
  {
   throw("this is always an error");
  }
  HBITMAP hBmp=NULL;
  Status status=bmp->GetHBITMAP(Gdiplus::Color::White, &hBmp); '

Comment: If that's always an error then the image isn't being loaded, so your problem is somewhere other than the `GetHBITMAP` call. Check the file path is correct. Check what the actual error code is. Do some debugging.